# NSNotificationCenter question

Tags: iphone, cocoa

Is there a way to know if an object is already registered as an observer for a particular notification?
In my implementation I have to add and remove the observers on the fly. For some reason, there is a random issue where the listener is receiving twice the same notification. I know I have to review my coding but It will be easier to fix for me if I could know this info.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way to query this information. If you need it, you need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a test by registering two observers with the same handler in the same object and It is being called twice. I thought the notification center would resolve this kind of situations. I will try to track this but i still think that it would be nice if I could query that to the center. Thanks again.

Comment: There is a solution for Jorge. As pointed out by SteveB. See another posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668372/coalescing-while-using-nsnotificationqueue

Comment: @Wayne That's a completely different issue. Jorge's question was about registering for the same notification twice. `NSNotificationQueue` is about coalescing multiple sent notifications into a single one. The two issues are not related.

Comment: Kevin, you are right. I got confused with the two. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into NSNotificationQueue. Here's the overview from Apple. It sounds like this could help you stop receiving duplicate notifications:

> NSNotificationQueue objects (or simply
>   notification queues) act as buffers
>   for notification centers (instances of
>   NSNotificationCenter). Whereas a
>   notification center distributes
>   notifications when posted,
>   notifications placed into the queue
>   can be delayed until the end of the
>   current pass through the run loop or
>   until the run loop is idle. **Duplicate
>   notifications can also be coalesced so
>   that only one notification is sent
>   although multiple notifications are
>   posted.** A notification queue maintains
>   notifications (instances of
>   NSNotification) generally in a first
>   in first out (FIFO) order. When a
>   notification rises to the front of the
>   queue, the queue posts it to the
>   notification center, which in turn
>   dispatches the notification to all
>   objects registered as observers.
>
> Every thread has a default
>   notification queue, which is
>   associated with the default
>   notification center for the task. You
>   can create your own notification
>   queues and have multiple queues per
>   center and thread.

Comment: Steve, thank you for shading the light. You helped me to find this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668372/coalescing-while-using-nsnotificationqueue

Comment: @Wayne Lo, great. Glad to help.