# How to unit/integration test classes that rely on NSNotificationCenter (in MonoTouch)?

Tags: c#, objective-c, testing, xamarin.ios, nunit

I am writing an iOS application using MonoTouch that has a lot of information to be entered on quite a few different screens. Information A, B, and C might be entered on Screen 1, but I need to display Info B on Screen 3 along with inputs for Information X, Y, Z and so on. The user can skip around from Screen 1 to Screen 7 and then back to Screen 3.

So, I created a static class to receive all of the information (via NSNotifications) and cache it. It also listens for requests for information (again, via NSNotifications) from the various screens, packages up the relevant information (in private static methods) from the cache and sends out another notification in response. This class should always have up to date information and therefore so should whichever screen the user jumps to.

```
public static class InformationFlowController
{
    static List<NSObject> _observers;
    static Dictionary<SomeEnum, Object> _data;

    static InformationFlowController()
    {
        _observers = new List<NSObject>();
        _data = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, Object>();

        _observers.Add(NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(Notifications.PayloadA, HandlePayloadA));
        ...
        _observers.Add(NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(Notifications.RequestA, HandleRequestA));
    }

    // receive information A
    static void HandlePayloadA(NSNotification ntf)
    {
        var infoA = (InfoA)ntf.Object;
        if (A == null) { /* throw an exception */ }

        if (_data.ContainsKey(EnumA))
        {
            _data.Remove(EnumA);
        }

        _data.Add(EnumA, infoA);
    }

    // receive request for info A
    static void HandleRequestA(NSNotification ntf)
    {
        InfoA info = null;

        if (_data.ContainsKey(EnumA))
        {
            info = _data.GetValue(EnumA);
        }

        // its up to the receiver what it wants to do if it gets null
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(Notifications.ResponseA, info);
    }
}
```

This all works fine.

**My question is how do I unit/integration test it?** 
Because of the nature of the app/policy/yadda-yadda, I have to have ~100% code coverage. Here is what I have tried and what I've run into.

The problem I am having trying to write an integration test for this is ensuring that if I make a request for information A that I get a response with information A.

```
[Test]
public void HandleRequestForATest()
{
    // setup the data in the IFC here

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(Notifications.ResponseA, delegate(NSNotification ntf)
    {
        var info = ntf.Object as InfoA;
        Assert.IsNotNull(info, "Info is null!");
        // some other asserts to check the data within info
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(Notifications.RequestA, null);        
}
```

The test passes with 0 asserts. I put a breakpoint on `var info = ntf.Object as InfoA;` and it never gets touched. I thought maybe its getting GC'd before it can receive a response, but I put a breakpoint in the `IFC.HandleRequestA` method and it is never getting called. Through inspection I can see that the notifications are getting registered with the DefaultCenter, but they don't seem to be getting fired.

In addition to all that, how can I test to make sure a notification is received within a certain amount of time and if it isn't, fail the test?  I tried adding a class variable:

```
bool assertsCompleted = false;
```

and modifying the test:

```
[Test]
public void HandleRequestForATest()
{
    // setup the data in the IFC here

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(Notifications.ResponseA, delegate(NSNotification ntf)
    {
        var info = ntf.Object as InfoA;
        Assert.IsNotNull(info, "Info is null!");
        // some other asserts to check the data within info
        assertsCompleted = true;
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(Notifications.RequestA, null);        

    NSTimer.CreateTimer(2, delegate
    {
        if (!assertsCompleted)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false, "Notification not received or Asserts not complete!");
        }
    } 
}
```

I put a breakpoint on `if (!assertsCompleted)` and that is not getting hit either.

Please help! :)

**EDIT2**
I changed the IFC class from static to non-static (as well as the methods) and that fixed the problem with the handlers not being called. This means I had to instantiate it in the AppDelegate and the TestFixtureSetUp, but I think we can live with this.
**/EDIT2**

Comment: [The other part of the question that was edited into another question is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4373079/639445)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
[Test]
public void HandleRequestForATest()
{
    // setup the data in the IFC here

    var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    InfoA info = null;

    var observer = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(Notifications.ResponseA, delegate(NSNotification ntf)
    {
        info = ntf.Object as InfoA;
        resetEvent.Set();
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(Notifications.RequestA, null);        

    Assert.IsTrue(resetEvent.WaitOne(250), "Reset event timed out!");
    Assert.IsNotNull(info, "Info is null!");
    // some other asserts to check the data within info

    //Make sure you do this! I'd put in try-finally block
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(observer);
}
```

Comment: I did not know about ManualResetEvent. This fixes part of the second problem.